# How install android sdk plugin from local machine?

Tags: android, android-2.2-froyo

I am a developer of Cuba, I can not download the package for Samsung Tablets, I have it on my local machine, but I can not install it, I believe the addon.xml seeks the root of D, as I can create this file? have no idea what format to have?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sounds like you have `addon.xml` somewhere saved on your local machine? If so, open it and look for `<sdk:url>`. Make sure that points to a zip file on your local machine.

Then, run `android` from your command line. In `Tools` menu, choose `Manage Add-on Sites...`.  Click on `New...` and point to your `addon.xml` file using the `file:///` protocol.

After that the Samsung Tablet should show up as an option in your Android SDK Manager for you to install.